# Installing packages in Racket

Tags: installation, lisp, racket, package

I installed DrRacket, the full version not the minimal but I don't have the packages.

When I run this code:

```
#lang racket

(provide (all-defined-out))

(require rsound)

(play ding)
```

It gives me this error:

```
standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: rsound
  collection: "rsound"
  in collection directories:
   C:\Users\Theodor\AppData\Roaming\Racket\6.3\collects
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects
   ... [161 additional linked and package directories] in: rsound
  no packages suggestions are available .
```

In "collects" I have only "catalog.sqlite".

How do I install packages for DrRacket? 
"Update catalog" didn't work.
The other similar questions didn't help.

Comment: Try  `raco pkg install some_module` in command line?

Comment: rako: undefined;
 cannot reference undefined identifier

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Author of rsound here. Yes, liweijian got it right, you need to install the package.  There are two ways to do this:

- In DrRacket, go to "File > Package Manager ..." and type "rsound" in the "do what I mean" box.
- Or, at the command-line, run

  ```
  raco pkg install rsound
  ```

Let me know if you have any problems with this!