# What do I tell Racket for it to allow me to use define-type?

Tags: racket

Scheme (Racket) newbie here.

I am trying to run some of the programs in this book [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K8sg.png)

I am on a Windows 10 machine. I downloaded Racket from here (https://download.racket-lang.org/)

I started up Racket.exe and it displayed a command line window (see screenshot below).

I entered this in the window:

```
(define-type WAE
  [num (n number?)]
  [add (lhs WAE?)(rhs WAE?)]
  [sub (lhs WAE?)(rhs WAE?)]
  [with (name symbol?)(named-expr WAE?)(body WAE?)]
  [id (name symbol?)])
```

Racket complained with this error message:

```
define-type: undefined;
 cannot reference an identifier before its definition
  in module: top-level
 [,bt for context]
```

I read on the website for the book that I should type this:

```
#lang plai-typed
```

I did so, and Racket complained with this error:

```
string:1:0: read-syntax: `#lang` not enabled
  possible reason: not allowed again inside a module that already starts `#lang`, or not enabled for interactive evaluation
```

What do I need to tell Racket for me to be able to use define-type?

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3K8sg.png) *Programming Languages Application and Interpretation* by Shriram Krishnamurthi.

[image: screenshot of CLI]

Comment: `racket -I plai-typed` might work.

Comment: Thanks @Shawn. I gave that a try and got this error: standard-module-name-resolver: collection not found
  for module path: (lib "plai-typed")
  collection: "plai-typed"
  in collection directories:
   C:\Users\costello\AppData\Roaming\Racket\8.8\collects
   C:\Program Files\Racket\collects\
   ... [172 additional linked and package directories]

Comment: Did you install the `plai-typed` package, e.g., using `raco`?

Comment: The `#lang` syntax is used at the tops of _files_, but not in the REPL. Invoking `racket -I plai-typed` should work if the `plai-typed` package has been installed. It seems that `plai-typed` was used in the second edition of the book, but it is now in its [third edition, where `plai-typed` is not used](https://www.plai.org/3/2/PLAI%20Version%203.2.2%20electronic.pdf#h.7yttkwa5a6jr).

Comment: Thank you @ad absurdum. I used DrRacket to install the plai-typed package (see  instructions here https://stackoverflow.com/a/34860624/1248535) and then started racket using: racket -I plai-typed. I am no longer getting an error with define-type.